# Python file dialog freezing issue while using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, asynchronous, tkinter, freeze

In order to print stuff on campus, I need to login to the webpage and submit the printing job manually on a browser, but I wanted to submit a job locally. So I wrote a small python script that uses Selenium to automate print job submission. I've verified that it works, but there's one thing that bugs me. Even after I select a file to print, the file dialog stays there until the actual code runs to the end.

The structure of the code is like the following.
1. Enter information on terminal (username, pw, which printer to use, how many copies, etc.).
2. Call tkinter.Tk().withdraw() to select a file (after selecting a file, "Submitting a print job..." is printed, as shown on the screenshot)
3. Do the actual Selenium job using information I collected above to submit a job

How can I make that file dialog disappear as soon as I select the file? Is it an ascyncio problem?

[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB First of all, thank you for your reply. I get your point why the screenshot is discouraged, but that screenshot doesn't contain error/code. I was just showing what's happening with the file dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that many other people were experiencing a similar issue. While many had solved the issue by adding *Tk().update()* before or after *askopenfilename()* line, my problem was only gone when *Tk().update()* line was added both before and after the *askopenfilename()* line. FYI, I'm running the script on macOS with python 3.7.